# Codeception error: Log path is not defined by key "paths: _logs"

Tags: symfony, codeception

I've just installed Codeception (using Composer) with Symfony 2.3 in a Vagrant box running on Windows 8.1. When I try to run tests using `bin/codecept run` or `bin/codecept run acceptance`, I get this error:
`Log path is not defined by key "paths: _logs"`

I do have a tests/_logs folder present. The codeception.yml is posted below. The weird thing is, when I change the name of _logs folder to anything else (for example 'log'), with a corresponding change to the "log" parameter in codeception.yml, I still get the same error message that refers to "_logs". Even if I delete the _logs directory and/or remove the reference to it in codeception.yml, I get the same error message. I tried reinstalling Codeception, restarting Vagrant, rebooting the computer, and still getting the same error.

My two teammates are able to run tests with the same code and with the same Vagrant box with no problems. The difference is that one of them is using a Mac OS and the other one is using a PC with Linux. Could this problem be related to Windows?

Here's my codeception.yml file:

```
      paths:
            tests: tests
            log: tests/_logs
            data: tests/_data
            helpers: tests/_helpers
      settings:
           bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
           suite_class: \PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
           colors: true
           memory_limit: 1024M
           log: true
     modules:
         config:
         Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:dbname=s2_at_test;host=127.0.0.1'
            user: 's2_at_test'
            password: #hidden#
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
            populate: true
            cleanup: true
```

Comment: Have you pasted the exact error message?

Comment: Expected message is: Log path is not defined by key "paths: log" 
https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.1/src/Codeception/Configuration.php#L152  What version of Codeception are you using?

Comment: Yes, this is the exact error message. In fact, the first time this message appeared, it was 'Log path is not defined by key "paths: log" ', just as you'd expect from the source code. When I change the directory name from log to _log, and then to _logs, the message would change accordingly. But now, the error message does not change anymore when I change the log directory name. It doesn't change even when I delete the log directory. I'm using Codeception 1.8.0.

Comment: I know this is over a year old, but did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Fels: Turned out this was somehow related to the Windows host machine. When I replaced Windows with Ubuntu on the host machine, and then reinstalled the Vagrant box, this error went away.